# Magento - Enable password reset in only 1 shop

Tags: magento, forgot-password, change-password, reset-password

I've been handed a website in magento.

The website has multiple subdomain shops, and I've been told that a previous developer removed the option for customers to reset their password. But now the client wants to enable this feature again, note however this features shall only be enabled for 1 subdomain shop.

Anyone know where i should look?

P's. I've been told the change has been made in one of the Magento files, on the ftp server, not via the admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you have not really provided enough information, but I will try anyway.

Assuming I was the developer who got that requirement I would rewrite the controller `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` and modify the `forgotPasswordAction` and `resetPasswordAction` to redirect to a 404 page, eg `$this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');`

So you have to see how your developer did it, then you can add a store specific check to allow it for that one website.

As for making changes live via FTP, hire a developer you only risk completely breaking your website if you do it that way. Use version controller and development server at the minimum.